# Adding a tail to lxml.etree.Element upon creation

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I know I can a tail to an element as follows:

```
tag = ET.Element(category, attrib=new_tag)
tag.tail= '\n'
```

Is it possible to add it during the instantiation? E.g.:

```
ET.Element(category, attrib=new_tag, tail='\n') # adds a "tail" attribute instead.
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If you do `ET.Element(category, attrib=new_tag, tail='\n')`, 'tail' is a normal attribute of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible.  Looking at the actual source code, this Element building method is enclosed in the file *lxml.etree.pyx* and is simply (without the docstring)

```
def Element(_tag, attrib=None, nsmap=None, **_extra):
    return _makeElement(_tag, NULL, None, None, None, None, attrib, nsmap, _extra)
```

Tracking down this `_makeElement` method, we find it in *apihelpers.pxi*, and it is declared as

```
cdef _Element _makeElement(tag, xmlDoc* c_doc, _Document doc,
                       _BaseParser parser, text, tail, attrib, nsmap,
                       dict extra_attrs):
```

Therefore, the behavior is exactly the same as in ElementTree, we can define a tag name, a dictionary of attributes, a namespace map (this is different from Element Tree), and a list of additional attributes which will be added to the attribute map.  One thing to note here is that the Element constructor is provided as a function in lxml unlike ElementTree's equivalent class.

The `Element` function can not take any extra positional arguments and any additional keyword arguments are used as attributes in the element.  There is simply no way to pass the value of the tail to the element constructor.  The `_makeElement` method is part of the private api and there is no easy way to access it, but if it could be accessed, this could provide a way to do it (notice that this function takes a value for the tail).

---

Of course, if we need such functionality, there is no reason why we can't just write a function to do so.<sup>**†**</sup>

```
def TailedElement(tag,attrib=None,nsmap=None,tail=None,**extra):
        x = ET.Element(tag,attrib,nsmap,**extra)
        x.tail = tail
        return x
```

Demonstrating this,

```
test = TailedElement("testel",{"testing":"yes"},tail="Tail Value")
ET.tostring(test)
# b'<testel testing="yes"/>Tail Value'
```

---

<sup>**†**</sup> There is a minor trade-off to this.  We can no longer specify an attribute named *tail* as an extra named parameter.  We can, however, still specify it by adding it to the attribute map.